# Error on messages after clicking the "Fetch Now" button

Tags: odoo

OpenERP v7 is giving me an error when I view the messages after I click the "Fetch Now" Button in `Settings > Email > Incoming Mail Servers > More > Messages`

This is the Error:

OpenERP Server Error

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 195, in dispatch response["result"] = method(self, **self.params) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1012, in search_read 
return self.do_search_read(req, model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1035, in do_search_read req.context) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 40, in proxy 
result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 28, in proxy_method 
result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 101, in send 
raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.exception_to_unicode(e), formatted_info)

Server Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 87, in send
return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 361, in dispatch_rpc
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 601, in dispatch 
res = fn(db, uid, *params) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 167, in execute_kw
return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {}) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 121, in wrapper 
return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 176, in execute 
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2356, in search 
return self._search(cr, user, args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, context=context, count=count) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/mail/mail_message.py", line 518, in _search context=context, count=count, access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4794, in _search 
query = self._where_calc(cr, user, args, context=context) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4643, in _where_calc 
e = expression.expression(cr, user, domain, self, context) 
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 371, in __init__
self.parse(cr, uid, distribute_not(normalize(exp)), table, context)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 468, in parse 
raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in domain expression %r" % (left, exp)) ValueError: Invalid field 'fetchmail_server_id' in domain
expression ['&', ('email_from', '!=', False), ('fetchmail_server_id','=', 4)]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Error says that `fetchmail_server_id` is not a field in the model which you are trying to search.

Please check in the database and `.py` file. May be you added in `.py` but forget to update the server then it will not added in database.

Comment: Please check in database for that model table.